# What are all of the implications of `-Wauto-import` in Xcode/Clang?

Tags: xcode, module, clang

While playing around with `-Werror`, I encountered `-Wauto-import`. It seems to suggest that I turn all `#import` statements which import system libraries/frameworks into @import statements. Is the warning only useful for making the use of modules explicit or are there other implications?

Example

```
#include <stddef.h>
// suggests change to 
@import Darwin.C.stddef;
```

Oddly enough, if I accept the suggested replacement, I receive a warning `expected unqualified-id`